# How to get a Map Control or Interaction

Tags: openlayers-3

How does one get a specific ol.control or ol.interaction from ol.Map? I have several dynamically added maps on a single page and I want to be able to access the ol.interaction.Select.

Comment: It's very unclear what do you need!

Comment: For example, how would I get the ol.interaction.Select interaction from a ol.Map? Something like myMap.getInteraction("ol.interaction.Select")...

Comment: Should be able to call `map.getInteractions()` or `map.getControls()`
https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/e848acd806d2cbb5e7134da9d05e0a48a48e0ac5/src/ol/map.js#L790

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
map.getInteractions().forEach(function (interaction) {
  if(interaction instanceof ol.interaction.Select) { ... }
});
```

Same thing for controls.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was doing (interaction.constructor.name === "DragZoom"). It was working in dev mode but not in production mode with webpack.